# Height auto inside parent with absolute position

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My component is something ad follows :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
outterDivStyles() {
    return {
        position: "relative",
        width: "100%",
        overflow: "hidden",
        /*height: this.props.height || 200*/
    }
}

innerDivStyles(){
    return {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: "1000%",
        transition: "left .5s",
        transitionTimingFunction: "ease"
    }
}
render(){
    return(
    <div>
            <div ref="detailsOutterDiv" className="detailsOutterDiv" style={this.outterDivStyles()}>
                <div ref="detailsInnerDiv" className="detailsInnerDiv" style={this.innerDivStyles()}>
                   <div className="slide" ><img src="http://placehold.it/250x200" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}
React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And the css is :

```
.detailsOutterDiv{
  background-color: #f00;
  /*height: 200px;*/  //if the height is 200px, then it's ok, but can it be done without that?
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.slide img{
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

Is there any way that the image shows with full height if the parent div has no specific height?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke8xg88q/).

Comment: fiddle not working

Comment: Not working because `height: 200px;` in css is commented. I want to solve it without specific width.

Comment: you should create a minimal example, without javascript

Comment: @giorgio Done. See the fiddle.

Comment: remove  the absolute div then you can see it would be shown

Comment: @RaniMorelesRubillos I know that. Can I do it without removing anything?

Comment: do position relative not absolute

Comment: so you want the div to have the same height as the image, right?

Comment: @QoP yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the height of `detailsInnerDiv` after the image loads.

In order to do that, you have to use `offsetHeight` to get the height, store it in the component `state` and assign it to `detailsOutterDiv`.

Something like this

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      height: 0
    };
  }  
  get outterDivStyles() {
      return {
          position: "relative",
          width: "100%",
          overflow: "hidden",
          /*height: this.props.height || 200*/
      }
  }
  get innerDivStyles(){
      return {
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          width: "1000%",
          transition: "left .5s",
          transitionTimingFunction: "ease"
      }
  }
  render(){
      return(
        <div>
              <div
                  ref="detailsOutterDiv"
                  className="detailsOutterDiv"
                  style={{...this.outterDivStyles,height : this.state.height }}
              >
                    <div 
                       ref={node => this.detailsInnerDiv = node}
                       className="detailsInnerDiv"
                       style={this.innerDivStyles}
                    >
                     <div className="slide" >
                       <img 
                         onLoad={() => this.setState({height:this.detailsInnerDiv.offsetHeight})}
                         src="http://placehold.it/250x200"
                       />
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/61843/)

Comment: The only problem is that children elements are in the parent component. My code is a little bit different. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/61848/)